# Use ieeetran.bst to display article ID instead of page numbers

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I am following the IEEE style manual which gives the following examples:

```
[1] M. Ito et al., “Application of amorphous oxide TFT to electrophoretic display,” J. Non-Cryst. Solids, vol. 354, no. 19, **pp. 2777–2782**, Feb. 2008.
[2] R. Fardel, M. Nagel, F. Nuesch, T. Lippert, and A. Wokaun, “Fabrication of organic light emitting diode pixels by laser-assisted forward transfer,” Appl. Phys. Lett., vol. 91, no. 6, Aug. 2007, **Art.ID. 061103**.
[3] J. Zhang and N. Tansu, “Optical gain and laser characteristics of InGaN quantum wells on ternary InGaN substrates,” IEEE Photon. J., vol. 5, no. 2, Apr. 2013, **Art. ID 2600111**.
```

Note that article ID at the end. How to I best encode this article ID in a bibtex entry? I currently use

```
  note         = {{Art. ID R115}},
```

but I am not sure this is the most versatile way. For example, there is an `eid` field in bibtex, which seems to be ignored by `ieeetran`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which BibTeX fields are supported largely depends on which bibliography style you are using.
The one recommended for use with the `IEEEtrans` class is `IEEEtran`.
The style itself is defined in `IEEEtran.bst` which does not mention the `eid` field, nor seems to have special handling for article ids.
Hence I would say that using the `note` field seems a valid choice.

Answer (score 1):

Many journals these days have not updated their style files to incorporate eid's, though an increasing number of journals use them. The [Bibulous](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/) project provides an alternative IEEE bibliography template that looks for an `eid` field in a given database entry if it does not find a `pages` field. The Bibulous-format [ieeetr.bst](https://github.com/nzhagen/bibulous/blob/master/templates/ieeetr.bst) style template file defines the following an article template:

```
article = <au>, \enquote{<title>,} \textit{<journal>} vol.~<volume>:{ }...
          [pp.~<startpage>--<endpage>|p.~<startpage>|<eid>|],{ }...
          [<month.monthabbrev()> ]<year>.[ <note>]
```

That is, if the `pages` field is not defined (so that the auxiliary fields `startpage` and `endpage` are likewise undefined), then it searches for an `eid` field and uses that instead.